# Get values from php assosiative array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get out the name of the first indexes "EMEA" and "IL" but without success. Any suggestions?

```
Array ( [EMEA] => Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [disposition] => ANSWERED 
    [numOfCalls] => 8 ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [disposition] => BUSY 
    [numOfCalls] => 8 ) 
  [2] => Array ( 
    [disposition] => FAILED 
    [numOfCalls] => 6 ) 
  [3] => Array ( 
    [disposition] => NO ANSWER 
    [numOfCalls] => 4 ) 
  ) 
  [IL] => Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
       [disposition] => ANSWERED 
       [numOfCalls] => 6 ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
       [disposition] => BUSY 
       [numOfCalls] => 2 ) 
     [2] => Array ( 
       [disposition] => FAILED 
       [numOfCalls] => 3 ) 
     [3] => Array ( 
       [disposition] => NO ANSWER 
       [numOfCalls] => 2 ) 
     ) 
  )
```

Comment: var_dump($yourArray['emea'][0]['disposition']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the expression you're looking for is

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
```

which allows you to iterate over an array and also see the key you're currently iterating over. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Applying this to your array, I'd say it's just a matter of writing

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
echo $key . "\n";
```

to get

```
EMEA
IL
```